# shutdown a hard drive

Tags: windows

How can you shutdown a harddrive ? i want to do this to be able to safely remove my sata drive even though it's hotplug. 
WMI does't seems to have the method.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading the question, I think this should be on http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: He said WMI, so I assume he wants to script his drive to safely shutdown. I always though serverfault was a poor idea, some questions easily fall into both SO sites.

Comment: ServerFault is a *great* idea even if its only result is to remove the hordes of non-programming-question-askers from our beloved SO :-) I understand it will also try to serve the needs of answering admin-type questions but that will just be a side-effect for me.

Comment: i want the API to do it in code ...

Answer (score 2):

Using WMI, you can get the 'eject drive' dialog to pop up using:

```
Shell "Rundll32.exe Shell32.dll Control_RunDLLA hotplug.dll", vbNormalFocus
```

Alternatively, if you want to programatically eject a device, you need [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165721). This should work with sata drives, if you can eject them manually then you'll be able to 'eject' them programatically.

Comment: the msdn article is insteresting

Comment: This method has nothing to do with WMI -- it's just launching the safely remove hardware dialog.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution without any popping dialogs:**

just use

```
sync
```

from [cygwin](http://cygwin.org) (sync is utility from [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/))